# How to Implement Search Bar with JQuery Tablesor

Tags: jquery, search, tablesorter

I have seen many tutorials on this site and others, including the tutorial from the tablesort website itself. However, every tutorial has resulted in an input box that does not sort my table. I am using the JQuery tablesorter plugin, and everything works fine, but only with the normal sorting. How can the I add a search bar that functions above the table and hides all rows that do not fit the search criteria. Currently, the Zebra widget is implemented and working properly.

Comment: can you share your attempt code in jsfiddle

Comment: @MohammedFarooq Do you want my current code? Or the code I tried that did not work?

Comment: Code which u tried and not worked.

Comment: @MohammedFarooq I can't get it right now, as I'm away from the computer I was using, but I'll add it when I get a chance

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way of doing the search, outside of the plugin.

```
<input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="tablesorter" placeholder="Search">
```

Using that as the search bar and the JS in the link below, I easily incorporated a search bar.

Here it is: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/tIuBL